# Flask-SQLAlchemy close connection

Tags: postgresql, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am using PostgreSQL and `Flas-SQLAlchemy` extension for Flask.

# app.py

```
app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE'] = 20
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

# views.py

```
user = User(***)
db.session.add(user)
db.session.commit()
```

Note that I am not closing the connection as suggested by documentation:

> You have to commit the session, but you don’t have to remove it at the end of the request, Flask-SQLAlchemy does that for you.

However, when I run the following PostgreSQL query I can see some `IDLE` connections:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_stat_activity;
```

Does it mean that I have a problem with Flask-SQLAlchemy not closing connections? I am worried about it because recently I got `remaining connection slots are reserved for non-replication superuser connections` error.

Comment: Can't speak for Flask, but the point of a connection pool is to keep some connections open to safe the overhead of opening new connections for every transaction.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SQLAlchemy sets up a pool of connections that will remain opened for performance reasons.  The PostgreSQL has a [`max_connections`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-MAX-CONNECTIONS) config option. If you are exceeding that value, you need to either lower your pool count or raise the max connection count.  Given that the default max is 100, and you've set your pool to 20, what's more likely is that there are other applications with open connections to the same database. `max_connections` is a global setting, so it must account for all applications connecting to the database server.